# Permission errors on insert after schema drop/create (Pg 9.0.23)

Tags: postgresql, backup, permissions, schema, connections

We have a web application that allows users to modify data through an API. In order to allow people to run tests, we provide a sandbox area called **'daily'**. This sandbox gets refreshed every day from the **'live'** database.

This works by dropping/creating a **'daily'** schema then copying over a subset of tables from the **'live'** schema. This is applied by running a simple SQL script via crontab every day (see below).

Issue:

- when the web application is started **after** the daily refresh, clients can insert data into the 'daily' schema as expected
- when the web application is started **before** the daily refresh, we encounter permission errors when trying to insert data, eg

  ```
  permission denied for relation annotation
  ```

Note: restarting the web application allows everything to work fine, but I would prefer to avoid the downtime.

Question:

- is this behaviour expected (Pg 9.0.23)?
- is there anything I can do to avoid this problem?

The script we are using to provide the daily refresh:

```
BEGIN;

drop schema if exists genome3d_data_daily CASCADE;

create schema genome3d_data_daily AUTHORIZATION genome3ddaily;

-- recreate sequence
create sequence genome3d_data_daily.annotation_id_seq;
select setval('genome3d_data_daily.annotation_id_seq', orig.last_value) from genome3d_data.annotation_id_seq orig;

-- create new tables (including constraints, indexes, etc)
create table genome3d_data_daily.annotation_type    (like genome3d_data.annotation_type including all);
create table genome3d_data_daily.annotation_segment (like genome3d_data.annotation_segment including all);
create table genome3d_data_daily.annotation         (like genome3d_data.annotation including all);

grant select on all tables    in schema genome3d_data_daily to PUBLIC;
grant select on all sequences in schema genome3d_data_daily to PUBLIC;

grant all privileges on all tables    in schema genome3d_data_daily to genome3ddaily;
grant all privileges on all sequences in schema genome3d_data_daily to genome3ddaily;

-- by default this will point to the original sequence
alter table genome3d_data_daily.annotation
alter column id set default nextval('genome3d_data_daily.annotation_id_seq');

-- insert data
insert into genome3d_data_daily.annotation_type     select * from genome3d_data.annotation_type;
insert into genome3d_data_daily.annotation_segment  select * from genome3d_data.annotation_segment;
insert into genome3d_data_daily.annotation          select * from genome3d_data.annotation;

END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a workaround that involved just deleting tables (and sequences) rather than dropping the schema. Leaving here in case it helps anyone else.

Changed the first few lines:

```
BEGIN;
drop schema if exists genome3d_data_daily CASCADE;
create schema genome3d_data_daily AUTHORIZATION genome3ddaily;
```

...to...

```
BEGIN;
create schema genome3d_data_daily AUTHORIZATION genome3ddaily;
END;

BEGIN;
drop table if exists genome3d_data_daily.annotation_type;
drop table if exists genome3d_data_daily.annotation_segment;
drop table if exists genome3d_data_daily.annotation;
drop sequence if exists genome3d_data_daily.annotation_id_seq;
```

This no longer disrupts existing database connections.